# Bazel list of tools in-scope for targets running shell commands

Tags: bazel

Is there a list of tools that are assumed to be always in the `PATH` when a Bazel target runs a shell command?

This is relevant for creating isolated build environments. AFAIU (see https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/50765#issuecomment-440009735) by default Bazel picks up tools from `/bin` and `/usr/bin` when in strict mode.

But what can ultimately be assumed about the minimal content of those? For example, I saw `awk` to be used liberally. But then `git` as well, which sounds border-line.

I imagine the exact set might correspond to whatever Google-internal Bazel expects to find in Google's build images `bin` directories. At least for `BUILD` rules open-sourced by Google.

Is there such a definitive list? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your assessment of the tool usage is correct, and unfortunately I'm not aware of such a list.

There should be one, and Bazel should treat the shell as a toolchain. Alas nobody is working on that at the moment. See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5265.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and pointing to that issue, will keep an eye on it.